# value passing on Winjs listview button click

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

### value passing on Winjs listview button click

Hi i am working on a winJS application.i have a winjs list and a button inside the listview.I need to pass a value on button click.

Answer (score 0):

suggest use 'iteminvoked' event on the listview.

```
test.html:
<div class="listview-host">
    <div id="listView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ selectionMode: 'none', tapBehavior: 'invokeOnly', swipeBehavior: 'none' }"></div>
</div>   

test.js:
WinJS.UI.Pages.define('/pages/test/test.html',
{
    ready: function onready(element, options)
    {   
        ...     
        listView.addEventListener('iteminvoked', this._oniteminvoked.bind(this));
    },
    _oniteminvoked: function oniteminvoked(event)
    {
    } 
}
```